# NPM global install of a package in Windows 10 results in Windows Script Host error

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, command-line-interface

I am following the tutorial for building a cli tool in Node here -- [How to Build a Command Line (CLI) Tool in Node](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-command-line-cli-tool-in-nodejs-b8072b291f81).

Environment:

- Cmder
- Node 9.5.0
- npm 6.11.3
- Windows 10

I am to the point where it has you create it as a shell cmd and the link it using `npm link`. Instead of running it in my shell--the same way create-react-app does--it instead errors with a Windows Script Host error:

```
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Invalid Character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error`
```

When I run `where npm`, I get:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
C:\Users\smkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\smkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd`
```

But when I run `where caph`, I get:

```
D:\Code\projects\cap-hooks\caph.js
C:\Users\smkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\caph
C:\Users\smkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\caph.cmd`
```

I'm pretty sure the error is because it's trying to open it from the local javascript file on the D drive, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm trying to make a CLI tool for fun/learning, and I want to be able to install the tool globally, but I haven't been able to proceed from here/fix this.

For reference here's the file and the package.json:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "caph",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "An automated cli package for generating administrative 
                       tools and components for React projects, written in 
                       React Hooks.",
  "main": "caph.js",
  "bin": {
    "caph": "./caph.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "smkarber",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`caph.js`

```
#!/user/bin/env node

console.log("Hello World!");
```

After running `npm link`, I can use `caph` in my shell, but it immediately gives me a Windows Script Host error instead of running it in the shell. I have tried numerous Github issues returned from Google as well as a handful of Stackoverflow questions, but nothing seems to directly refer to fixing this situation, and I am unable to rectify the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be `/usr/` not `/user/`. So `caph.js` should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems so obvious now.

Comment: Hmm... I'm facing the same problem, but even though I add `#!/usr/bin/env node`, I still get the error from Windows Script Host. It seems that shebangs don't work on Windows.